# Forwarding Slim HTTP requests to Guzzle client

Tags: php, http, curl, slim, guzzle

I am using Slim on a REST API server.  Some of the endpoints need to blindly be proxied to to another server, and I am using Guzzle for this part.  It works most of the time to just use the Slim request as the Guzzle request (with some minor modification such as the host, etc).

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as SlimRequest;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as SlimResponse;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzleRequest;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response as GuzzleRequest;

$app->post('/bla/bla/bla', function (SlimRequest $slimRequest, SlimResponse $slimResponse) {
    $slimRequest = $slimRequest->withUri($slimRequest->getUri()->withHost('https://example.com'));
    $guzzleResponse=$this->httpClient->send($slimRequest);
});
```

One of my endpoints uses multipart content, and the files nor the POST content is being sent.  As an alternative, I've tried the following but without success.

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as SlimRequest;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as SlimResponse;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzleRequest;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response as GuzzleRequest;

$app->post('/bla/bla/bla', function (SlimRequest $slimRequest, SlimResponse $slimResponse) {
    $headers = array_intersect_key($slimRequest->getHeaders(), array_flip(["HTTP_CONNECTION", "CONTENT_LENGTH", "HTTP_ACCEPT", "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE", "CONTENT_TYPE"]));
    $guzzleRequest = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request($slimRequest->getMethod(), $slimRequest->getUri()->getPath(), $headers, $slimRequest->getBody());
    $guzzleResponse=$this->httpClient->send($guzzleRequest);
});
```

If necessary, I will resort to manually creating the [multipart form](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart), however, I expect there is a better way to do so since both are PSR-7 complient.

How should this best be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

PSR-7 Request objects are IMMUTABLE. That is, you cannot alter the values. Setting something new will return a *new instance*.

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/

So, just change

```
$slimRequest->withUri($slimRequest->getUri()->withHost('https://example.com'));
```

to

```
$slimRequest = $slimRequest->withUri($slimRequest->getUri()->withHost('https://example.com'));
```

Also, `$slimRequest->getUri()->withHost('https://example.com')` returns a Request object too. What you need here is:

`$slimRequest->getUri()->withHost('https://example.com')->getHost()`

which will give you your string.

Comment: Good point.  Actually was doing so, however, didn't show in my example script.  Doesn't help with the multipart forms.

Comment: You mean adding `$slimRequest = `?  Just did so.

Comment: Ok, but the stuff in brackets is another request, not a string URL, so you need to sort that bit next

Comment: ie. withHost() returns another Request Object

Comment: Try changing the bit in brackets to `$slimRequest->getUri()->withHost('https://example.com')->getHost()`